# Help with attribute on front-end and php code

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, attribute-set, custom-attributes

So I have an attribute showing up on front end for each product.

Front-end (Currently): [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtbeQ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEVcq.png

What I need: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtbeQ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/COctc.png

Back-end code:

```
<div style="text-align:left;"><h style="color:#93c455;">✓</h><?php $features = $_product->getAttributeText('features');?> 
<?php echo implode("</br> ✓ ", $features) ;?></div>
```

What do I need to achieve this? I need all the attributes showing with different icons next to them. I need all attributes showing and a green check mark on those that are selected on admin, and I need the the text of those not selected to be less opacity than the ones that are selected.

Can anyone help with this?

---

This is how my admin looks....

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some backend code:

```
<ul class="attr-custom-list">
    <?php foreach($features as $feature): ?>
        <li><span class="icon <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($feature); ?>">✓</span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($feature); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Essentially you style it by class and name of feature. You don't provide info about where icon come from. If css then add it by class and if by img then just add it to provided code (in li element).
This approach give you max flexibility and simplicity if you not familiar with Magento or PHP

---

There will write in foreach all options for used ID. Just need to be combined and use if statement to add class select to right one:

```
   <ul class="attr-custom-list">
    <?php
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load(149);
    $attributeOptions = $attribute->setStoreId($storeId)->getSource()->getAllOptions(false))
    if($attribute->usesSource()) {
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
        foreach($options as $key=>$value): ?>
            <li><span class="icon <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($value); ?>">✓</span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($value); ?></li>
        <?php endforeach;
    }

    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes I need all of them showing and the ones selected I need them having green checkmarks, and the ones not selected to have no check marks and different color text.

Comment: For the icons they would basically will come from img... How can I have it showing different icons for the different attributes?

Comment: No problem. Added more code to help list all options. You get selected options and all. Now you can combine it in one foreach and use if to add class to selected one. After all you have complete solution.
Thanks for accepting answear :)

Comment: Thank you so much. One question where would I indicate the different icons?

Comment: in foreach you can add domething like this:
`<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('img/'icon_'.$this->escapeHtml($value).'.png') ?>" />`
this will choose img in your skin catalog  by value. just name it correctly.